# How to convert a list of &str into a list of static &str?

Tags: rust

So I'm new to Rust and working on a string exercise and have the following:

```
pub fn anagrams_for<'a>(word: &str, possible_anagrams: &[&str]) -> HashSet<&'a str> {
    let mut my_hashset: HashSet<&'a str> = HashSet::new();
    for anagram in possible_anagrams {
        if is_anagram(word, anagram) {
            my_hashset.insert(anagram);
        }
    }
    return hs;
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
explicit lifetime required in the type of `possible_anagrams`: lifetime `'a` required
```

How do I add this in Rust?

EDIT: One other question - how would I add this without modifying the function parameters passed in? Do I need a new mutable variable that clones possible_anagrams? I'm asking because I think the kata won't let me have control over what is passed in initially. But I will have control over what I can do to the parameter once I'm inside the function.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify lifetime for slice's `&str`s

```
pub fn anagrams_for<'a>(word: &str, possible_anagrams: &[&'a str]) -> HashSet<&'a str> {
    let mut my_hashset: HashSet<&'a str> = HashSet::new();
    for anagram in possible_anagrams {
        if is_anagram(word, anagram) {
            my_hashset.insert(anagram);
        }
    }
    return my_hashset;
}
```

[rust.playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9649d0a6a4523e9205bcb686332933ab)

Comment: Is `anagrams_for`'s signature (parameters and return type) is predefined elsewhere? Because signature w/o changes looks broken.

Comment: hmm...it's part of a coding challenge type exercise, so I thought you shouldn't change the function param types. But changing it the way you suggested makes it work.